# How to install Leiningen on linux?

Tags: linux, clojure

I've just installed Ubuntu. I want to install Leiningen so that I can get going with Clojure. But it seems that downloading process in Linux is very different than Windows.

In [its Github repository](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/stable/README.md), it says to **Download the script**; but when I click on the link, I just get a page with code. How do I download it?

Answer (score 3):

Right-click on the link, "Save Link as".

Comment: yes but if I do that in OS X I get lein.txt, not lein.

Comment: I just renamed it and it worked. `mv lein.txt lein`

Answer (score 0):

run this on linux:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/technomancy/leiningen/stable/bin/lein
```

And place it on your $PATH

Answer (score 0):

You also need to make it executable, i.e

```
curl -s -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/technomancy/leiningen/stable/bin/lein -o /usr/local/bin/lein
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/lein
```